# Is there a way to prevent ActiveRecord from querying objects of id=0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my database, I've set all foreign keys to be `unsigned int not null default 0`. As a result, in my Rails app, I get a lot of queries for objects of id=0. Here's an example:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

In the console, if I do this:

```
Foo.new.bar
```

then this query gets run:

```
SELECT `bars`.* FROM `bars` WHERE `bars`.`id` = 0 LIMIT 1
```

I've tried monkey-patching but method_missing doesn't seem to be able to catch these kinds of calls. I really don't want to (can't really at this point) change my schema. The only way it seems I can get around this is by manually always checking for bar_id != 0, but that doesn't seem very clean.

Ideas/suggestions?

Just to clarify, **I do not want to change the schema**. The question is: Can ActiveRecord be configured/hacked such that both 0 and nil are considered invalid ids thus preventing any queries for object of id=0?

Comment: Why are you calling "bar" on a newly instantiated Foo object?  The reason it's querying for 'where bar.id = 0' is because bar_id IS 0 on your Foo object.

Comment: it's just an example to illustrate the point.  just imagine a real Foo instance with bar_id=0.

Comment: Are you saying all queries or are you trying to prevent things like find or find_by_id from working with 0?

Comment: for now, i'd be happy if i could block any/all generated by a belongs_to (e.g. foreign_id = 0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the migration solution anyway. I'll happily remove it if

> ...can't really at this point change my schema

is shown to be true. In a new migration file:

```
def up
  change_column_default(:bars, :id, nil) # removes default, letting it be null
  execute "update bars set id = null where id = 0"
end

def down
  change_column_default(:bars, :id, 0)
  execute "update bars set id = 0 where id is null"
end
```

Comment: I don't want to change the schema because I'd have to take down the database.  In any case, I'm not looking for a schema solution; I want an application-level solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using conditions in the belongs to method. Conditions create a default where clause that must be satisfied through any active record query.

```
belongs_to :bar, :conditions => "id != 0"
```

Comment: nice idea! unfortunately, it results in this:
`SELECT bars.* FROM bars WHERE bars.id = 0 AND (id != 0) LIMIT 1`